# Change my R environment language (Ubuntu)

Tags: r, ubuntu

Consider that as an example:

```
> mean(eta)
# [1] NA
# Warning message:
# In mean.default(eta) : l'argomento non è numerico o logico: restituisco NA

> Sys.setenv(LANG = "en")
> mean(eta)
# [1] NA
# Warning message:
# In mean.default(eta) : l'argomento non è numerico o logico: restituisco NA
```

My renviron file, still not working:

```
### etc/Renviron.  Generated from Renviron.in by configure.
###
### ${R_HOME}/etc/Renviron
###
### Record R system environment variables.

Sys.setenv(LANGUAGE='en')
R_PLATFORM=${R_PLATFORM-'i686-pc-linux-gnu'}
## Default printer paper size: first record if user set R_PAPERSIZE
R_PAPERSIZE_USER=${R_PAPERSIZE-'a4'}
R_PAPERSIZE=${R_PAPERSIZE-'letter'}
## Default print command
R_PRINTCMD=${R_PRINTCMD-'/usr/bin/lpr'}
```

I think the problem is:

```
Sys.getenv(LANG)
Errore in Sys.getenv(LANG) : oggetto "LANG" non trovato
```

Also:

```
Sys.getenv(LANGUAGE)
Errore in Sys.getenv(LANGUAGE) : oggetto "LANGUAGE" non trovato
```

Also:

```
> sessionInfo()

R version 3.0.1 (2013-05-16)
Platform: i686-pc-linux-gnu (32-bit)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=it_IT.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=it_IT.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=it_IT.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=it_IT.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=it_IT.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=C                 LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=it_IT.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] entropy_1.2.0 ineq_0.2-11   moments_0.13 

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.0.1

> system("uname -a")

Linux lucas-K55VD 3.11.0-14-generic #21-Ubuntu SMP Tue Nov 12 17:07:40 UTC 2013 i6
```

Also:

```
> 2+x
Errore: oggetto "x" non trovato
> Sys.getenv("LANG")
[1] "it_IT.UTF-8"
> Sys.setenv(LANG='en')
> Sys.getenv("LANG")
[1] "en"
> 2+x
Errore: oggetto "x" non trovato

> Sys.setenv(LANG="en_US-UTF-8")
> 2+x
Errore: oggetto "x" non trovato
> system("locale -a | grep '^en'")
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_COLLATE to default locale: No such file or directory
en_AG
en_AG.utf8
en_AU.utf8
en_BW.utf8
en_CA.utf8
en_DK.utf8
en_GB.utf8
en_HK.utf8
en_IE.utf8
en_IN
en_IN.utf8
en_NG
en_NG.utf8
en_NZ.utf8
en_PH.utf8
en_SG.utf8
en_US.utf8
en_ZA.utf8
en_ZM
en_ZM.utf8
en_ZW.utf8

> Sys.setenv(LANG="en_US.utf8")
> 2+x
Errore: oggetto "x" non trovato
```

Also another thing: how am I supposed to show R output or code here if stackoverflow keeps blocking my attempts to show other people code or console outputs?

Comment: try `Sys.getenv("LANG")` and `Sys.setenv(LANG='en')` ...

Comment: Well half problem solved, still not working thought.

Comment: how about `Sys.setenv(LANG="en_US.UTF-8")` ?

Comment: also try `system("locale -a | grep '^en'")`

Comment: Something very wrong going on here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way I've been able to get around the problem was to install Rstudio and type on the console:

```
> Sys.setenv(LANGUAGE="en_US.utf8")
> 2+x
Error: object 'x' not found
```

No clue still why that doesn't work when typing on Ubuntu terminal thought.

Answer (score 4):

See `help(Startup)` -- you have to set this in, say, `~/.Renviron` so that it is set before the main R process starts.

Comment: please tell me which line I need to change in Renviron file

Comment: The problem is there's no such object LANG or LANGUAGE on my environment that's why it's not working.

Comment: results of `sessionInfo()` and `system("uname -a")` please?

Comment: @Thomas: That's wrong. `Renviron` does not take R commands but rather environment `VAR=value` assignments. See `help(Startup)`.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel My bad. You're right. I was thinking Rprofile.